# C# syntax highlighting not working in VS code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

[image: Second programm]
[image: first programm]

When i create new project everything works fine, but if i create new project in same directory (first programm \lesson1\task1, second programm \lesson1\task2) syntax highlighting and suggestions stopped working.
[image: task1]
[image: task2]

i tried to reinstall C# dev kit plugin, but nothing works. I asked my classmates, they have same issue

Comment: Have you added the second project to your solution as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a guess here but it seems that the second project falls back to the default syntax highlight instead of using [Semantic Highlighting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview). The difference is that semantic highlightning is provided by the language server which knows a lot more about the code then the more generic highlighter.

This is most likely due to the C# extension loading your solution (`GeekBrains.sln` in your case) and only finding the first project.

To add a project to your solution you can execute the following command in the project root (where `GeekBrains.sln` is located).

```
dotnet sln add lession1/task2/task2.csproj
```

Or if you are in the folder for the second task.

```
dotnet sln ../../GeekBrains.sln add task2.csproj
```

The extensions should pick up this change but I've had instances where I had to restart the language server.

Another way to do it is to open te command palette in VSCode (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is the default I think) and finding ".NET: Add Existing Project..." if you find that easier.

Comment: Thats is working perfectly fine. Thank you!
Im new to programming so i have a question. What .sln does? it takes all projects inside the main folder and using it as a part of big programm, so i need to add all programms there to make everything work? if i dont add it, Vs code treats it like something that not relevant for main programm?
Thank you again)

Comment: The .sln file is used to group several projects in to a larger "solution".  It doesn't have to be projects in the same folder even though it usually is. As a rule of thumb you want all your projects added to your solution file, but in certain cases you might have several solution files that only loads part of your whole project at a time.